# How to query all record be nested in record column with suffix is datetime

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a field `markedDates` (type: RECORD).

`markedDates` have some propertis like this:

I have no idea how did designer create this table but data was saved like this:

[image]

I have to SUM all earnedPoint with some datetime filter (something <= now <= something). But I am a newbie with Google Big Query.
Problem is in markedDates there are other datetime.: d_2018_09_08, d_2019_09_09,..
I have to sum earned point in other date too. 
I have researched, but cannot find out anything.

Could you give me some keyword in this case or how to query in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: In this table there is a field `userID`. Expected output is sum all earned point of user with datetime filter. (>= 2019/09/10 AND <= 2019/12/31).

Comment: which field is used for datetime filter?

Comment: I think we have to use `markedDates.d_2018_11_30`. Inside it there is not any datetime filed.

Comment: it is record with no anything that looks like date or datetime - rather than name of field itself.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I cannot query it like a array.

Comment: It seem like a partitioned column. But i cannot find that keyword on internet. Have partitioned table only

Comment: record is not equivalent of array. in schema you presented  - there is no array (REPEATED RECORD) but rather SCTRUCTS(NULLABLE RECORD )

Comment: Have no way to query like that? So if i have to sum earned point, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to SUM all earnedPoint ...

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT userID, SUM(markedDates.d_2018_11_30.earnedPoint) AS allEarnedPoint
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY userID
```

> ... with some datetime filter

don't see any datetime related field that can be used for such filtering

> Problem is in markedDates there are other datetime.: d_2018_09_08, d_2019_09_09,...   And i have to sum earned point in other date too

Below does the trick

```
#standardSQL
SELECT userID, SUM(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'"d_.*?":(.*)'), '$.earnedPoint') AS FLOAT64)) allEarnedPoint
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(markedDates), r'"d_.*?":{.*?}')) x
WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'"d_(.*?)"') BETWEEN '2018_12_02' AND '2018_12_05'
GROUP BY userID
```

you can test, play with above using quite over-simplified dummy data that I hope represent your case

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 userID, 
    STRUCT(
      STRUCT(0 AS earnedPoint, TRUE AS earnedShare) AS d_2018_11_30,
      STRUCT(1 AS earnedPoint, TRUE AS earnedShare) AS d_2018_12_01,
      STRUCT(2 AS earnedPoint, FALSE AS earnedShare) AS d_2018_12_02,
      STRUCT(3 AS earnedPoint, TRUE AS earnedShare) AS d_2018_12_03,
      STRUCT(4 AS earnedPoint, FALSE AS earnedShare) AS d_2018_12_04,
      STRUCT(5 AS earnedPoint, TRUE AS earnedShare) AS d_2018_12_05,
      STRUCT(6 AS earnedPoint, TRUE AS earnedShare) AS d_2018_12_06
    ) markedDates
)
SELECT userID, SUM(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'"d_.*?":(.*)'), '$.earnedPoint') AS FLOAT64)) allEarnedPoint
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(markedDates), r'"d_.*?":{.*?}')) x
WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'"d_(.*?)"') BETWEEN '2018_12_02' AND '2018_12_05'
GROUP BY userID
```

Note: should work as is with your data - but even if you will need to do some adjustments - you should get good idea from above

Comment: Problem is in markedDates there are other datetime.: d_2018_09_08, d_2019_09_09,...

Comment: so, update your question to clearly present your case!

Comment: I try your query but get an error: `Bad double value: {\"float\":1,\"integer\":null,\"provi...`. It seem like `earnedPoint` is null.

Comment: [Troubleshooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubleshooting)